# Java Swing Dynamic Grid Layout

Tags: java, swing, grid, jbutton, dimensions

I am trying to create a grid in Java Swing with a menu next to it. In the menu there will be options to change dimension of the of the grid for example 3x3, 4x4, 5x5...
When the user clicks on a dimension the grid should change to what he chose. Can someone give an idea or a code snippet on how to do it. I was thinking oh a 2d array for the JButtons so create as many buttons as needed for when selecting the grid dimension. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason not to use [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html)?

Comment: @VGR I am using a GridLayout but I need to make the user able to change the dimensions of it. Currently I set it up to be 3x3 but I'm trying to find a way to make it dynamic and changeable to what the user chooses from the menu.

Comment: Add a JSpinner or JFormattedTextField, add a listener to that field, and in that listener, call the setRows and setColumns methods of your GridLayout.